# How to obtain roo shell access programmatically?

Tags: java, spring-roo, add-on

I'm trying to create a roo add-on and thus some custom commands. Is there a way to check if the user has filled in one of the options of the command he/she is typing? For instance, the user is typing the command:

```
say hello --name MyName --album SomeAlbum --song
```

Now, just when he is supposed to enter a song and he presses the TAB key, I want to make a check that he has already introduced an album. Is there any way to read the buffer string he/she has entered so far?

I suppose that I would need to access the current shell instance somehow, but so far I couldn't find any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `MethodTarget` class there is a method called `getRemainingBuffer()`, which returns the content of the current line entered in the console. An object of this type is one of the arguments of the `getAllPossibleValues` method which needs to be implemented in a converter, which is needed for custom types of commands.

That seems to be it.